# appcompat_v7 errors different api

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I am very new to android programming and new to eclipse and SDK/JDK in general. I've come across tutorials and currently following 2 of them. I want to resolve all these red x marks that I get every time I create a new android application project and googling hasn't gotten me specific solutions.

I've downloaded and installed the current SDK and JDK

I then went to install new software from Help > Install New Software... > Add Repository > https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

and now I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz70d.jpg

I went to check the errors and have noticed the Android Resources are at a different API level than what I installed from the SDK Manager, my cell phone is on 4.4.4 kit kat so it would make sense to work on 4.4 kit kat from the SDK Manager but the Android Resources is at API 21 while I'm on API 19. Is this due to API incompatibility?

I needed +10 reputation in order to post images so I uploaded the images on imgur instead and posted the link. Sorry in advance to make you go through the troubles of opening another link.

Comment: As you are new to android dev, I suggest you starting with Android Studio. In any case, open your SDK Manager and you should be able to update your api and support libraries level.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Compile with SDK version` in project properties to `21` and you should be good to go. Then clean the project and rebuild it

Comment: But the only Project Build Target is the Android 4.4.2 which is API 19. I don't see anywhere that I can change the API but rather the target instead. If I need to go API 21 then I'd have to install android 5.0 from SDK Manager but I don't even have the version on my cell phone to test.